# Encode to Url Javascript in Jquery Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery Datatable :

this is my function:

```
datatable.dataTable(dataTableOptions);

            //row details
            function format ( d ) {
                return '<b>Url Google: </b>' + d.URL_Google;
            }

            datatable.DataTable().on('click', 'tr[role="row"]', function () {
                var tr = $(this);
                var row = datatable.DataTable().row( tr );

                if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            } );
```

When i click on my row, it display under the hmtl URL: 
[[image: Jquerry Data table [1]]

I don't want to display the whole web link. I want to display only 'Google URL' in my table and i want to be able on a single click to open a new browser and access the link.

Is it possible to do that?

My try: 
    //initialize datatable
                    datatable.dataTable(dataTableOptions);

```
                //row details
                function format ( d ) {
                    return '<a href="'+d.URL_Google.encodeURI()+'"><b>Url Google </b></a>';
                }
```

Comment: Please show an attempt so that we may help where you are stuck.

Comment: Ive just put update: encodeURIComponent encodeURIComponent is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function format ( d ) {
                    return '<a href="'+d.URL_Google+'" target="_blank"><b>Url Google </b></a>';
                }
```

Comment: try to do console.log(d), what it is returning?

Comment: VM988:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined. When I click on the rows of my table there is no response.... :/ Just add the missing part... Maybe will help!

Comment: on the else part use console.log(row.data());

Comment: I need to see the output of `console.log(row.data());` so please put it before `row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();`

Comment: (index):745 Uncaught TypeError: d.URL_Google.encodeURI is not a function
    at format ((index):745)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> ((index):760)
    at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184258/discussion-between-ray-a-and-simon-gis).